# Realtek R8168 network driver 8.034.00 not compiling under CentOS 5.8 64-bit

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, drivers

I'm trying to compile Realtek R8168 driver 8.034.00 on CentOS 5.8 64-bit and I got this:

```
    make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5/build SUBDIRS=/r8168-8.034.00/src clean
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5-x86_64'
  CLEAN   /r8168-8.034.00/src/.tmp_versions
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5-x86_64'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5/build SUBDIRS=/r8168-8.034.00/src modules
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5-x86_64'
  CC [M]  /r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.o
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:55:28: error: linux/pci-aspm.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
In file included from /r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:68:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168.h:294:1: warning: "DMA_BIT_MASK" redefined
In file included from include/asm-generic/pci-dma-compat.h:7,
                 from include/asm/pci.h:135,
                 from include/linux/pci.h:886,
                 from /r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:41:
include/linux/dma-mapping.h:16:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:68:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168.h:1297:1: warning: "netdev_for_each_mc_addr" redefined
In file included from /r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:42:
include/linux/netdevice.h:190:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘__check_duplex’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:277: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘__check_autoneg’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:280: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘__check_aspm’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:283: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_init_board’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:14474: warning: left shift count >= width of type
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_init_one’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:14868: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_poll’:
/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.c:17129: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
make[2]: *** [/r8168-8.034.00/src/r8168_n.o] Błąd 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/r8168-8.034.00/src] Błąd 2
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-308.16.1.el5-x86_64'
make: *** [modules] Błąd 2
```

How to fix this ? Kernel-devel is installed. I'm using latest kernel: 2.6.18-308.16.1.el5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug. Newer version fixed this problem.